# youtube api v3. Automatic check if the uploaded video is available to other users

Tags: .net, api, youtube, video-processing

I'm using YouTube Data API v3 Client Library for .NET to upload videos from a server to a YouTube channel. Everything goes well until some duplicated videos appear. These videos are shown to users as duplicated, but I can't find the way to check that with the .NET library. I am trying these 2 api commands:

1. PlaylistItems: list

   youtubeService.PlaylistItems.List("contentDetails,id,snippet,status");
2. Videos: list

   youtubeService.Videos.List("id,liveStreamingDetails,snippet,contentDetails,fileDetails,player,processingDetails,recordingDetails,statistics,status,suggestions,topicDetails")

But the results set doesn't contain anything which could point to the fact that the video is duplicated. Can anybody give a hint where to search for that? There is Status in the results set, but that's only Video Privacy Status (unlisted, private, public)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wow. Seems like that result data has been recently added. Now Status contains not only privacyStatus, but also uploadStatus and rejectionReason.